# on_player_eos event not working when trying to play through a list of mp3 files with Pyglet

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyglet

I'm trying to shuffle a list of mp3 files and then play through them with pyglet. Once the player runs out of sources I want to re-shuffle the list, and then play through them again. This process would happen infinitely. I have been able to get pyglet to play through the sources once, but the on_player_eos event is never fired when I run out of sources. I'm not sure exactly what I am doing wrong, or if I am approaching it in the wrong way. I've tried a couple ways of doing it, but have had no luck getting it to work. Here is the code

```
import os, sys, random, pyglet
from random import shuffle

song1 = pyglet.media.load('beats/breathe.mp3', streaming=False)
song2 = pyglet.media.load('beats/everything.mp3', streaming=False)
song3 = pyglet.media.load('beats/jazz.mp3', streaming=False)
player = pyglet.media.Player()

# Play beatz

def beatz():
    playlist = [song1, song2, song3]
    shuffle(playlist)
    player.queue(playlist[0])
    player.queue(playlist[1])
    player.queue(playlist[2])
    player.play()

def on_player_eos():
    print('repeating')
    beatz()

player.on_player_eos = on_player_eos

pyglet.app.run()
```

I have also tried replacing the 'player.on_player_eos = on_player_eos' with

```
player.push_handlers(on_player_eos)
```

But it doesnt seem to do anything either. Any help appreciated.

UPDATE:

I was able to get this to work by simply adding 'streaming=False' to each song variable. Streaming sources in pyglet can only be queued once on a player object, while static sources can be queued as many times as you want.

With recognizing the event 'on_player_eos', I also wasn't aware of the pyglet event loop. In order for pyglet to pick up the events I wanted it to, the code below had to be run.

```
pyglet.app.run()
```

This fixed my problems.